# Atualizar div com retorno PHP após requisição Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Opa,

Tenho a seguinte função para um login em ajax

```
            function show_login_client_enter(id) {
                var url = 'store/content/validate_user_client_action.php';
                var method = 'POST';
                var params = 'id_store='+id;
                params += '&user_acao=1';
                params += '&user_email='+document.getElementById('user_email').value;
                params += '&user_pwd='+document.getElementById('user_pwd').value;
                var container_id = 'loading_validate_client_action_login';
                var loading_text = 'Loading...' ;
                ajax (url, method, params, container_id, loading_text) ;
                $(document).ajaxComplete(scripts);
            }
```

No arquivo PHP validate_user_client_action.php, quando o usuário logar eu preciso dar um refresh numa div com dados de outro arquivo php, mas, como chamar uma função ou como dar um refresh num retorno php de uma requisição ajax?

Preciso no retorno do login no php de algo como:

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#loading_client_content_info").load("store/content/client_info.php");
</script>
';
```

Este código de .load, não retorna nada, nem no console.

Comment: Não poderia fazer com que **validate_user_client_action.php** retornasse o que deveria retornar de **client_info.php** ? Pois a forma como está tentando é redundante, além de não fazer sentido.

Answer (score -1):

Então, tentei entender o que você queria e cheguei a isso. Se não for exatamente isso, vamos tentar resolver de outra maneira!

```
//Primeira chamada AJAX
function show_login_client_enter(id){
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'store/content/validate_user_client_action.php',
  data: { id_store: id, user_acao: '1', user_email: document.getElementById('user_email').value, user_pwd: document.getElementById('user_pwd').value },
  beforeSend:function(){
    // O código aqui dentro será executado antes do envio, podemos colocar o loading aqui por exemplo!
    //$('#algumaDiv').html('<div class="loading"><img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
  },
  success:function(data){
    // A request foi bem sucedida, agora temos o retorno em "data"
    console.log(data); // Abre o console e você vai ver a resposta!
    //Chama a outra função
    pegaClientInfo(data.algumaCoisa);
  },
  error:function(){
    // A request falhou! Diga ao usuário
    $('#algumaDiv').html('<p class="error"><strong>Algo errado!</strong> Tente novamente.</p>');
  }
});  
}

//Segunda chamada AJAX
function pegaClientInfo(algumaCoisa){
    $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'store/content/client_info.php',
  data: { param: algumaCoisa}, //Envia o parametro que você precisar para pegar os dados do cliente neste arquivo
  beforeSend:function(){
    // O código aqui dentro será executado antes do envio, podemos colocar o loading aqui por exemplo!
    //$('#algumaDiv').html('<div class="loading"><img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
  },
  success:function(data){
    // A request foi bem sucedida, agora temos o retorno em "data"
    console.log(data); // Abre o console e você vai ver a resposta!
    $("#loading_client_content_info").html = data;
  },
  error:function(){
    // A request falhou! Diga ao usuário
    $('#algumaDiv').html('<p class="error"><strong>Algo errado!</strong> Tente novamente.</p>');
  }
});
}
```

Se você reparar, as chamadas tem callbacks para algumas situações. Ex: Antes de enviar, caso tenha sucesso ou caso falhe! Você pode fazer o que você quiser :)

O que eu fiz foi, realizei a primeira chamada(validate_user_client_action), caso tenha sucesso, chamamos a segunda(client_info) e a partir desta você pode atualizar sua div com os dados do cliente!